If $a$, $r_k$ coprime to $m$, then $ar_k \equiv r_j \mod m$ for $r_j$ less than and coprime to $m$?
I have the set $\{r_1, \ldots, r_{\phi(m)}\}$ where each $r_k$ is less than and coprime to $m$, and an integer $a$ that is less than and coprime to $m$. I managed to show that $ar_k$ is coprime to $m$ by writing $a$ and $r_k$ as linear combinations equal to one and multiplying the linear combinations with each other. I would like to show that $ar_k \equiv r_j \mod m$ for some $j$, so that $ar_k$ when reduced mod $m$ is less than and coprime to $m$. This seems to be true just experimenting with some integers, but I'm having a tough time figuring out how to prove this. I had the thought of multiplying by the inverse of $r_j$, so that we want to show $ar_kr_j' \equiv 1 \mod m$. Therefore we'd have to show that the inverse of $ar_k$ is less than and coprime to $m$ but that hasn't been easy either. Could I have some help to get me on the right path? Thanks for your time.

All you have to do is prove that if $x\equiv y\bmod m$ and $\gcd(x.m)=1$ then $\gcd(y,m)=1$, right?

Ah, you can make the congruence an assumption and not the goal! So if $ar_k \equiv c \mod m$ then $mi = ar_k - c$ for some $i$ so that $ar_k = mi + c$. We also have that $ar_kx+ my = 1$ for some $x, y$, so therefore $(mi + c)x + my = 1$ and $mix + cx + my = 1$ so $cx + (xi + v)m = 1$ and therefore $c$ and $m$ are coprime! Wow!

I encourage you to post what you now know as an answer.

It suffices to show that if $ar_k \equiv c \mod m$, then $c$ is coprime to $m$, as there will be such a $c_j$ such that $0 < c_j < m$ and therefore $c_j = r_j$ for some $j$. So, let $ar_k \equiv c \mod m$, so that $mi = ar_k - c$ for some $i$, and therefore $ar_k = mi + c$. Further since $ar_k$ and $m$ are coprime we have that for some $x, y$
\begin{split}
1 &= ar_kx + my
\\
&= (mi + c)x + my
\\
&= mix + cx + my
\\
&= cx + m(ix + y)
\end{split}
And therefore $c$ is coprime with $m$!
